# Getting "File name too long" error on php wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a wordpress website running on the server. Previously, everything was working fine but from last two days I am getting weird errors in apache2 logs as you can see below:
**Access Logs**

```
[23/Feb/2024:10:39:33 +0000] "GET /index.php-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined/each/poduct_id=4&ku=br1qpjdda92fwfm7ums.rifling HTTP/1.1" 403 286 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15 (Applebot/0.1; +http://www.apple.com/go/applebot)" "17.211.217.110"
```

**Error Logs**

```
[Fri Feb 23 10:42:07.266182 2024] [core:error] [pid 7961] (36)File name too long: [client 172.11.16.23:2958] AH00036: access to /index.php-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined/each/poduct_id=088&ku=br31cygyr22f22/5s.transpirable failed (filesystem path '/var/www/html/index.php-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined')
```

I have no clue how to handle this and what's the reason for that weird url hit

Comment: The User Agent from the log entry indicates that this request was likely made by Apple's web crawler - but how it came up with that defective URL to begin with, we can't say. If it actually "found" that as a URL somewhere in your site, then there should probably be other log entries as well, by other web crawlers.

Comment: Those multiple occurrences of `undefined` might(!) indicate, that JavaScript is involved in the creation of that URL somewhere.

Comment: I didn't receive any entry from any other web crawler.

Comment: Please check the [tag:wordpress], [tag:apache] tags and [help/on-topic] for what they have to say about configuration questions (as opposed to programming): Stackoverflow is for programming-related questions.

Comment: @OlafKock although I don't think we can definitively say that this _is_ caused by configuration, at this point.

Comment: @CBroe If this question truly was about programming wordpress, I'd expect to see code and a [mcve] to reproduce. As it is (without any own code that OP seems to have touched), it's surely _software_ related, but rather to the software's _use_, than its _development._